# Load sybase .db into new sybase developer server

Tags: sybase

We've got a few .db files laying around here which were created by Sybase (version 8.x, I guess) and I've the task to extract some data from those old databases.

Now I've installed the latest Sybase developer version (15.7) and want to add these databases to the sybase server.

Unfortunately I do not have any experience with sybase and I couldn't find any documentation in the official sybase manual for this task.

Is this even possible? Does anyone of you know about an article describing the integration of existing complete databases or the necessary commands for the task?

Comment: I think you are confusing your Sybase Products. Sybase 15.7 is Adaptive Server Enterprise. The Sybase 8.x is likely Adaptive Server Anywhere/SQL Anywhere.  Your will need to make sure you are trying to load them into the correct software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DB files are SQLAnywhere files, so first you will need to get SQLAnywhere.  Sybase has some documentation on upgrading databases from earlier versions [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/sachanges_en11/unloading-reloading-upgrading-newjasper.html).

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to load the .db files from SQL Anywhere directly into Sybase ASE, they are totally different products.

If you have SQLAnywhere, Developer Edition available here:

https://www.sap.com/cmp/syb/crm-xu15-int-sqldevft/index.html

You can upgrade the .db files and use them in SQL Anywhere.

Once upgraded and accessible in SQL Anywhere, you can use Sybase ASE's bcp program to copy each table to a file and bcp them into Sybase ASE.